# error: linking to Fortran libraries from C fails (compile octave from source)

Tags: octave, configure

I try to compile octave from source, on Ubuntu 20.04 following instructions here:

https://wiki.octave.org/Building

before which i have installed dependencies according here:
https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems

Then I got the following error

```
checking g++ compiler version number... 9.4.0
checking whether stl_algo.h is broken... no
checking gcc compiler version number... 9.4.0
configure: defining __NO_MATH_INLINES avoids buggy GNU libc exp function
checking for sin in -lm... yes
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking whether the compiler supports GNU Fortran 77... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... no
checking whether a usable Fortran compiler was found... yes
checking how to get verbose linking output from gfortran... -v
checking for Fortran 77 libraries of gfortran...  -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13 -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/glibc/lib -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/gcc/current -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath
checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... unknown
configure: error: in `/home/sunxd/octave-8.3.0/.build':
configure: error: linking to Fortran libraries from C fails
```

Inside the config.log, I found

```
configure:18457: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c -lm   -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/current/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/     13 -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/glibc/lib -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/gcc/current -L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath >&5     ¬                                                                                                                                                        
2160 /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':¬                                                   
2161 (.text+0x16): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'¬                                                                                                  
2162 /usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'¬                                                                                     
2163 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status¬                                                                                                              
2164 configure:18457: $? = 1¬                                                                                                                                 
2165 configure: failed program was:¬                                                                                                                          
2166 | /* confdefs.h */¬
```

using `env |grep PATH`  (advice from Vladimir)

```
MANPATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man::
WINDOWPATH=2
INFOPATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:
PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/sunxd/
```

I have commented out the script of linuxbrew from .profile already but still linuxbrew is there.

```
# eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

log out and log in again linux brew is away now.

following advice from Ian, I have get rid of f2c alreay.

now the configuration passed.

Comment: What operating system is this, MacOS? What is this fort77 package supposed to contain? Be aware you already had gfortran according to the configure output.

Comment: OK, I found that the fort77 is a wrapper to f2c. Just get rid of it, it is useless. Don't get fixated on the 77 revision of the Fortran standard mentioned in the configure. Just ignore it, it is irrelevant noise.

Comment: There is some clash of your GCC versions, using GCC 9.4.0 (quite old, but probably the main distribution compiler suite) as the compiler, but linking with libraries from GCC 13. Regarding *"How come the configure script automatically find homebrew as the library path?"* ... You would have to show us your environment variables. Execute `env` and see where the linuxbrew is mentioned. You can use `grep`.

Comment: Get rid of f2c as well if you can. That is from prehistory, use a proper compiler nowadays, i.e. this millennium.

Comment: Please don’t edit “solved” into the title. Instead, post an answer an accept it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer